# Layer Interference: Reverse diffraction oder?

Tags: optics, interference

Brief in between question: Regarding the conditions for constructive interference on thin layers $m\,\lambda = 2\,d\,\sqrt{n-\sin^2(\alpha)}$, where $\alpha$ is the angel of incidence. For simplicity let's consider $n = 1$ hence $m\,\lambda = 2\,d\cos(\alpha)$ and no phase shift. $\textbf{But}$ doesn't that mean the lower orders of diffraction are on the outside? For instance the zeroth order had to be at $\alpha = 90^{\circ}!$ $\left[\alpha = \arccos\left(\dfrac{m\,\lambda}{2\,d}\right)\right]$

Comment: 1.what do you call "on the outside" 2, in the 90° direction you will never be able to observe anything, since reflection is small to zero and the incoming light is in the way.

Comment: I'm just confused as you because the formula predicts the zeroth order to be at $90^{\circ}$ where it actually should be centred at $0^{\circ}$. Compared to a grating where $\sin(\alpha) = m\,\dfrac{\lambda}{d}$

Comment: With outside I mean diffracted light by an angle close to $90^{\circ}$, inside close $0^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 1):

I can't se your difficulties,  the zeros order  of positive interference can can not bei seen at thin films, same thing with reflecting grates. The grating and thin film have different behavior. why do you expect the same?

Comment: Well, but if you were to look at the reflected light coming from a thin layer then there have to be multiple angles $\alpha_n$ where the light constructively interferes. Each point is labeled with an order of diffraction $n$. My confusion is based on the fact the highest order is layered at the center ($\alpha_n = 0^{\circ}$) and the lowest on the outside $(\alpha_0 = 90^{\circ}$). Probably that's how it is.